# Can you legally use real life things and events as concepts for portfolio building?

Tags: legal, portfolio

I'm super new to all this and I have a question on portfolio building when you don't have any client work to show yet.
Am I allowed to use real life things as concepts?
I mean: let's imagine I see a poster for a local beer festival, or a concert of a band I like and I want to do something like that. Of course the artwork would be completely different (I don't want to rip off the artist), just for the same event.
Am I allowed to show this in my portfolio if I clearly describe it as a fake work and not a commissioned one?
Thanks

Comment: Sure, so long as you're not trying to pose it as something officially validated and aren't making a profit from it. Deception or trying to hurt someone (or some event's) else's reputation is bad, but using real events can be a good idea. Don't use any logos/branding that are copyrighted though.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Please don't ask legal questions here - they are off-topic. There's a [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) for such questions. In any case you could avoid any such problems by simply changing the names of events/bands etc to fictitious ones, and create fictitious logos etc. That way you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I'm merely trying to figure out how to start building a portfolio, didn't realise the question is inappropriate here.

Comment: You could reframe this question to be asking about common practice or best practice and leave strict legality out of it, and then it would fit here perfectly - perhaps an edit?

Comment: A famous British agency in the 90's called Attik out of Huddersfield did this - created campaigns around famous brands in their folio such as Nike that they were not actually working for. They went on to great success with offices in the US and Australia and would probably deny this now although in their own words " self-promotion is everything" Famously they produced a printed book called Noise which featured none commercial work and they flogged it mercilessly across the country and promoted it in magazines like Creative Review. It worked in establishing their name.